# How can I get the attribute value?(javax.xml.bind.annotation)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Im using javax.xml.bind.annotation and I need to get the attribute "xmlns:language" (see below xml)

```
    <type xmlns:language="ru" xmlns:type="string">Some text</type>
```

What annotation should I use?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "type")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Type {
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String language;
}
```

Comment: `xmlns:language` isn't an attribute it is a namespace binding. You are binding the namespace `ru` to the namespace prefix `language`. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: If you have control of the XML format then it would be much more appropriate to use an `xml:lang` attribute for this purpose rather than a namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the document from your question you are declaring that the prefix `language` will be associated with the namespace `ru`.

```
<type xmlns:language="ru" xmlns:type="string">Some text</type>
```

I do not believe the above is what you are trying to do.  If you are trying to specify the language for your document  I would recommend using the `xml:lang` attribute instead (as suggested by Ian Roberts).

```
<type xml:lang="ru">Some text</type>
```

**Type**

Then you would map to it as follows using the `@XmlAttribute` annotation:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Type {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "lang", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
    protected String language;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Type.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader(
                "<type xml:lang='ru' xmlns:type='string'>Some text</type>");
        Type type = (Type) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(type, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<type xml:lang="ru">Some text</type>
```